# Java keytool - illegal option deststorepass:file

Tags: java, linux, shell, keytool

Thanks for your time. I'm trying to create a java keystore from a PKCS12 file.

This has worked before, but I've done some work to remove password visibility from the command line, using the command `keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass:file ...`

This functionality is apparently available in Java > 7:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

> **-storepass[:env|:file] argument** Note: All other options that require passwords, such as -keypass, -srckeypass, -destkeypass -srcstorepass, and -deststorepass, accept the env and file modifiers. (Remember to separate the password option and the modifier with a colon, (:).)

but for some reason I get the message: `Illegal option:  -deststorepass:file`

Does anyone please know what I am doing wrong here, or how to correctly use the keytool command with the :file modifier?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the keytool that comes with java 1.7+? This option seems to have been added in 1.7.

Comment: Huh, I was going to say that same thing but then I did some tests and couldn't get it to fail that way. Turns out I was testing a newer version of java than I thought. Yeah, that's probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you're both totally right. What a fool- I had set the java version to 1.7, but neglected to `update-alternatives --set keytool [path]`. Thanks both for your eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the java version to 1.7, but neglected to also set the keytool to the appropriate version.

```
update-alternatives --set keytool [path]
```